# I want to know the difference between "you are false" and "you are wrong"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

What is the difference between *false* and *wrong*? Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: This question might be better suited for ell.stackexchange.com depending on the motivation. *You are false* is an old-fashioned way of calling someone a liar or unfaithful. It has little overlap with you are wrong.

Answer (score 6):

To call someone false implies they are deceptive, disingenuous, dishonest, or unfaithful, etc. The "false" in "false prophet" implies the prophet is actively deceptive. It doesn't necessarily mean what they are saying is wrong, but that they are out to trick you.

So:

> You are false: *You are deceptive.*
>
> You are wrong: *You are incorrect.*

Comment: This comes closest (I think) to the correct answer. If you could add how *wrong* is substantially different from false, it would be impeccable. (I already up voted.;))

Comment: Everyone "knew" that the Q was GR. Few really knew **this.** +1 !

Answer (score 3):

False and wrong are two different concepts.

[False](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/false) is the absence of truth.

[Wrong](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wrong) is the state of not being correct.

The difference between the two is *very* subtle, but it exists.  This difference is best illustrated by actions:

You can do something the wrong way.  It is challenging to do it the false way.

People can be both false and wrong, but they mean different things.

Someone who is wrong is not correct.  What they are saying may, in fact, be false, but it does not imply deceit.  Rather, it is a statement of factual incorrectness.

Someone who is false is someone who is not truthful.  In other words, they are lying.  In general, this is reserved for people who are being deceitful on purpose.  You would not call someone who is incorrect false.  This is generally an insult.

Answer (score 1):

If by false, you mean that the person is lying, there are words to give that distinction.

If you question the **accuracy** of a statement you question if he is right or wrong.

If you question the **veracity** of a statement you question if he is lying or not.

Answer (score 0):

A fact that is not true can be described as false or as wrong, pretty much interchangeably.

When a person is described as 'wrong' it means that they are incorrect. However describing a person as 'false' it means that they are a habitual liar, or that they are unfaithful. (If a person is 'false to their vows' they have broken their vows. If they are 'false to a person' then they have betrayed the trust of that person).

Describing a person as false is fairly archaic these days.

Comment: There is no bacon on my plate. That is TRUE. That is also wrong. -- There IS bacon on my plate. That is FALSE. That is also wrong.